# wso2 indentity server 5.10.1 - role-based adaptive user authentication var hasRole is always false

Tags: wso2, multi-factor-authentication, wso2-identity-server

We use WSO2 5.10.1 for SSO and I am trying to get adaptive MFA working but having some trouble. The IP-based adaptive authentication template works, but for some reason, the role-based template does not. For some reason, the variable `hasRole` always returns `false`, even though my test user is a member of the internal role called `staff2`. staff2 is an internal role containing only the test user.

The `wso2carbon.log` with the info is below. I also included the script I am using, which is the default role-based template PLUS a few modifications I made to get a little more information in the log.

Log:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-02 10:14:34,684] [badcbf3d-288c-4d3a-8abc-372763d87e0b]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.config.model.graph.js.JsLogger} - Working so far
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-02 10:14:34,684] [badcbf3d-288c-4d3a-8abc-372763d87e0b]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.config.model.graph.js.JsLogger} - false string info
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-02 10:14:34,684] [badcbf3d-288c-4d3a-8abc-372763d87e0b]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.config.model.graph.js.JsLogger} - <testuser> Has one of Roles: [staff2]
```

My Code:

```
// Role-Based from Template...

// This script will step up authentication for any user belonging
// to one of the given roles
// If the user has any of the below roles, authentication will be stepped up
var rolesToStepUp = ['staff2'];

var onLoginRequest = function(context) {
    executeStep(1, {
        onSuccess: function (context) {
            // Extracting authenticated subject from the first step
            var user = context.currentKnownSubject;
            // Checking if the user is assigned to one of the given roles
            var hasRole = hasAnyOfTheRoles(user, rolesToStepUp);
            Log.info('Working so far');
            Log.info(hasRole + ' string info');
            if (5 > 1) {
                Log.info(user.username + ' Has one of Roles: ' + rolesToStepUp.toString());
                executeStep(2);
            }
        }
    });
};

// End of Role-Based.......
```

Comment: If I replace the "if (5 > 1) {" with it's original code "if (hasRole) {" , the executeStep(2) function is never called because hasRole is always false for some reason. Please help! I have tried to change the variable 'rolesToStepUp' with many combinations of quotation marks, various different formats ' or ", changing it to other role names and had no luck.

Comment: It seems like the issue may be related to my user store. Do I need to define a preferred user store or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `rolesToStepUp` variable as follows and try out.

```
var rolesToStepUp = ['Internal/staff2'];
```

If you use the variable as `var rolesToStepUp = ['staff2'];`, it checks whether the user has a role named 'staff2' in the PRIMARY userstore. For example, if you create a Role by selection domain- PRIMARY and role name- staff2, the user who gets assigned to that role will be able to go through 2 steps according to your script.

If you want to use a role other than a role attached to PRIMARY userstore, you need to define the domain in the `var rolesToStepUp` array.
Since you have created an internal role, `var rolesToStepUp` should be defined as `var rolesToStepUp = ['Internal/staff2'];`

Comment: YOU ARE MY HERO ANURADHA! I thought I tried that formatting but I believe I did not capitalize the I in the word Internal and now it is working with the proper formatting. Thank you so much !!!