# wso2 identity server 5.7.0 How write Script for Role1?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I want Use this link:

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Adaptive+Authentication

I want Role1 Can't Login to my Application and Write this Code:
and it's Don't Work and Role1 can login to my application.
How can Write this script?

```
  // Role-Based from Template...

// This script will step up authentication for any user belonging
// to one of the given roles
// If the user has any of the below roles, authentication will be stepped up
var rolesToStepUp = ['Role1'];

function onLoginRequest(context) {
    executeStep(1, {
        onSuccess: function (context) {
            // Extracting authenticated subject from the first step
            var user = context.currentKnownSubject;
            // Checking if the user is assigned to one of the given roles
            var hasRole = hasAnyOfTheRoles(user, rolesToStepUp);
            if (hasRole) {
                Log.info(user.username + ' Has one of Roles: ' + rolesToStepUp.toString());
              return false;
            }
        }
    });
}

// End of Role-Based.......
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you didn't get the log `Log.info(user.username + ' Has one of Roles: ' + rolesToStepUp.toString());` check your condition. If your Role is an internal role, change `rolesToStepUp` variable as follows and try out.

   `var rolesToStepUp = ['Internal/Role1'];`

   Have a look on https://stackoverflow.com/a/66013019/10055162 for more details
2. In order to fail the user login, just returning false doesn't work. Use `sendError` utility function (https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Adaptive+Authentication+JS+API+Reference#AdaptiveAuthenticationJSAPIReference-sendError(url,parameters)).
   Check user-age-based script for sendError usage (https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Configuring+User-Age-Based+Adaptive+Authentication)